# Outlook Translator returns error when with on-prem exchange server

Tags: outlook-addin, microsoft-translator, exchange-server-2016, on-premises-instances

Environment consists of on-prem Exchange Server 2016CU22 in a DAG configuration sitting behind a Barracuda ADC load balancer configured to load balance POP3, SMTP, and Outlook 2016 client connections(instantSSL service).  Have added the Outlook Translator add-in both on the exchange server and also directly into Outlook.  When trying to translate an email, receive the following error:

An error occurred. Please try again.
Session Id: 28db8d22-13bf-403b-9a3b-4ca69ca705d6

We also have a test exchange server, same version and CU.  When configuring an outlook profile to connect to the test server, the translator add-in works perfectly every time.  Have been working with Microsoft for over a month and they cannot figure out where the issue lies.  They suggested posting to this forum to see if anyone else has run into this issue.  They said that since translation communication happens between the client and the microsoft translation site, the server and load balancer should not come into play.

When using OWA and turning browser debugging on, we can see connections from the client out to https://eu.ogma.osi.office.net/outlooktranslatorapp/api/translate that just sit in a pending state.  But when connecting to the test exchange server, these connections complete immediately.

We are at a loss to where the problem lies.  Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: StackOverflow is for "programming questions".  Q: Did somebody from Microsoft Technical Support really tell you to post here???  SUGGESTIONS: Try https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/home/contact, or https://serverfault.com/

Comment: the url it's trying to connect to is an Office owned processor, before it talks to Microsoft Translator site. It seems that this connection is not working. I'd suggest to support to route this to Office, ogma specifically, for debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  Microsoft support sent me the link to this forum to post the question, so yes they really asked me to post here.  I will take your suggestion for serverfault.com, and also reply to them that they try routing to Office support.  They obviously have no idea where the problem lies.